# Javascript loop to update image is returning broken image

Tags: javascript, loops

I am new to javascript and am trying to create this loop to simulate some dice rolls. When I click roll none of the images are refreshed and it ends with the broken image shown. Can anyone see where my error is?

```
    function roll(){
        for(x=0;x<10;x++){ 
            var die_num1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*6);
            for(y=0;y<20;y++){
                var picturetype1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
                if (picturetype1 == 1){prefix1 = "die-";}
                if (picturetype1 == 2){prefix1 = "dicet-";}
                if (picturetype1 == 3){prefix1 = "dices-";}
                document.getElementById("dice").src='http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/dice/' + prefix1 + die_num1 + '.gif';
            }
        } 
    }
```

body:

```
    <input type ="button" value = "Roll" onclick="roll()" >
    <img name="dice" id="dice" src="http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/dice/die-1.gif" >
```

I used a`document.write` to make sure that at least the final image existed in my folder and it does. I would expect to see the images cycling through as the loop progresses though. Again, I have no experience with javascript and have put this together based on how I thought it should look. Any help will be appreciated.enter code here

Comment: The main reason this wont work is because it just goes to fast. It doesnt take in account the loading time of an image. For the human eye it you would only see the last image from the loop.

Comment: Thanks svenbravo. I have tried implementing the setTimeout() event as I thought this may have been the cause but I had no success there either. I will recreate and update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for setting me in the right direction. I have reworked this to use setTimeout as Michael suggested and it is working great. Only needed 1/10 of a second per iteration, not much but made all the difference.

```
function roll2(){
    var timer = setTimeout ("roll2();", 100);
    i++;
    if(i >= 15) clearTimeout(timer);
    var die_num1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*6);
    var picturetype1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
    if (picturetype1 == 1){prefix1 = "die-";}
    if (picturetype1 == 2){prefix1 = "dicet-";}
    if (picturetype1 == 3){prefix1 = "dices-";}
    if (i <=15) {
        document.getElementById("dice").src='http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/dice/' + prefix1 + die_num1 + '.gif';
    }
    if (i >=15) {
        document.getElementById("dice").src='http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/dice/die-' + die_num1 + '.gif';
        i=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect browser as an event-driven environment even to consider updating the screen before you return from you `roll()`. You need to get acquainted with `setTimeout` and handle it as a sequence of timer events.

Comment: I got acquainted. Thanks for the tip Michael!